# OpenOffice Calc SUM of TRUNC number cells, with rows that include text cells

Tags: openoffice-calc, floor

RE: Apache OpenOffice 4.1.7, AOO417m1(Build:9800) - Rev. 46059c9192, 2019-09-03 12:04.

---

I need to sum non-integer entries across a range of cells, but without including the decimal values (complicated by some cells being text). I started with **ROUNDDOWN**, then **TRUNC**, then **FLOOR**. I'm driving myself nuts trying to find a clean code (or even an arbitrarily extensible ugly code) for what would be the following:

`=SUMIF(ISTEXT(R7:CL7);0;TRUNC(R7:CL7))`

The above doesn't work, of course, since **TRUNC()** doesn't apply to ranges, but it conveys what I'm trying to do in a nutshell -- some of the cells contain text, which **SUM()** ignores (luckily), but they flummox **TRUNC**, so I needed to handle the text problem.

I started with **ISNUMBER**, just to get the ball rolling; **ISTEXT** has fewer characters, but it's not worth fixing that right now.

**FLOOR** was equally disappointing for ranges:

`=SUM(FLOOR(R7:T7;1))`

I tried variations of **=SUM(IF(...** and searches for **ROUNDDOWN** range (and variations on that) and such pseudocode as "*IFTEXT*" and "*SUMTRUNC*" (and variations on that). I found info on **ROUNDDOWN(SUM(...** and so forth, but not "*SUM(ROUNDDOWN(...*" or any equivalent.

In my delirium, I got silly and even tried:

`=SUMIF(ISTEXT(S7:U7);0;AND(TRUNC(S7);TRUNC(T7);TRUNC(U7)))`

To be clear: {2.9→2 + 2.9→2 + 2.9→2 = 6} ≠ {2.9+2.9+2.9 = 8.7→8}. I'm looking for a 6, not an 8 (I'd joke about sixes and sevens, but I'm way past pumpkin o'clock and 2.428571 takes up too much space).

My current test-kludge is:

`=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(R7);ROUNDDOWN(R7);0);IF(ISNUMBER(S7);ROUNDDOWN(S7);0);IF(ISNUMBER(T7);ROUNDDOWN(T7);0); ... ;IF(ISNUMBER(AX7);ROUNDDOWN(AX7);0))`

It ends at AX7 only because of the char count. I hope to **SUM** the whole row in a single sweep, but that ain't gonna cut it. I could do it in large chunks in multiple cells, and then add those cells up, but oy gevalt.

Since it's already ugly anyway, I could use the following to save a few characters, but this would only mean being able to extend the range maybe 6 further cells (not much point in that):

`=IF(ISTEXT(R7);0;TRUNC(R7))+IF(ISTEXT(S7);0;TRUNC(S7))+IF(ISTEXT(S7);0;TRUNC(S7))`

I'm seriously considering simply going down a bunch of rows (to below my data cells) and entering the following, then copying the cell and pasting it to a complementary range, and telling the **SUM** cells to just sum up their respectively shadowed rows (instead of the data rows that they sit in):

`=IF(ISTEXT(R7);0;TRUNC(R7))`

Sorry for the rambling; I need sleep. This started as a need, then multiple failed attempts became a grudge match of principle and obstinacy, and now I'm just plugging away at it out of blind habit developed over the past 2-3 days (hopefully I won't forget what the purpose was).

In summary...: ++?????++ Out of Cheese Error +++DIVIDE BY CUCUMBER.

I'm comfortable enough with macros, though it's been ~7 years (and that was in Excel). Thanks in advance, even if the answer is that I'm stuck with one of these!

---

EDIT: I don't see a way to attach a .csv here (though I could open the .csv with Notepad, and copy-and-paste the contents if that would help anyone), so here's a set of pics:

[image: AO3 quarter-hourly traffic pic 1]

[image: AO3 quarter-hourly traffic pic 2]

[image: AO3 quarter-hourly traffic pic 3]

Comment: How does your input data look like? Please provide a screenshot or (even better) some CSV data.

Comment: @tohuwawohu :  I couldn't find a way to attach the .csv, so I've added some screenshots.